# What are the most important considerations when designing Redux actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If I have a situation: a component has **3 operations**(list all info || search needed info || filter info), but all of these operations depend on **same API**, just different parameters.

I'd like to know what is the best approach to design Redux actions? To design 3 actions that are mapping the 3 operations? Or just 1 action because of just 1 API？

What are the most important considerations when designing Redux Actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it should be one or two or three actions really depends on how your reducers are organized, and on how your UI is connected to your store.

You should think of API calls as side-effects of your actions, and not as the actions themselves. Your redux store holds a particular state of your UI: what filter is active ? What is the current search query ? and the like...

The most important consideration when designing actions is : what do they mean for the state of my UI? What impact do they have on it ? How do they relate to my store's state ?

If your concern is to mutualize API calls code, there are various patterns to handle that : use a simple helper function taking parameters, use something like redux-saga to trigger side-effects, etc.. But all in all, API calls shouldn't be relevant when designing actions.

Comment: Thanks :) I've understood what should focus on and to build my system better.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the docs that says that actions should map to API endpoints. So you shouldn't have to think of how many API endpoints you have.

From http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html:

> Actions are payloads of information that send data from your
>   application to your store.

In your case though, if one action with payload can accomplish the result and mutate your `state` to the desired condition, I don't see a reason to use three (and thus have three reducers, etc).

Comment: "and thus have three reducers".. three actions do not imply three reducers, once reducer could very well handle the three actions

Comment: Thanks..I think i should refer to the doc again :)

Answer (score 0):

The redux docs have a good section on how asynchronous actions/API usage should work within a redux app.

http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

I've followed this pattern, using the thunk middleware, and found it to work really well. The idea is to give your actions the ability to return a function. You will have:

- A "main" function that will dispatch that the application is making an API call, make the API call, and handle the results.
- Two pure action creators (functions that return an object with a type and any number of other properties) that will pass the information related to the API call to your reducers.

The actions:

```
/* Inside ./action.js */

/* This is the function you will dispatch from another component (say, a container component. This takes advantage of thunk middleware. */

export function fetchAllInfo() {

  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestAllInfo())

    /* Import your API function, make sure it takes a callback as an argument */
    API.fetchAllInfo((allinfo) => {
      dispatch(receiveAllInfo(allinfo))
    }
}

/* Pure action creators */
function requestAllInfo() {
  return {
    type: "REQUEST_ALL_INFO",
  }
}

function receiveAllInfo(allinfo) {
  return {
    type: "RECEIVE_ALL_INFO",
    allinfo,
  }
}
```

The reducer:

```
/* Inside ./reducer.js */

export function inforeducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "REQUEST_ALL_INFO": {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        /* This can be passed as prop so a component knows to show a loader */
        isFetching: true,
      })
    case "RECEIVE_ALL_INFO": {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        allInfo: action.allInfo,
      })
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So with thunk middleware (or your own way of dealing with asynchronous dispatching) and a callback on each API call, you can use this method to work with API calls dispatching at both the beginning of the call and when you receive results.